# InterestRate is returning to 0, the reference I used is from another Form

Tags: c#

Brand new to C#, I've already posted on here once today and I appreciate all the help I can get! I have a program I am creating in Visual Basic. The form has one Master Form - the `AccountForm.cs`, three off shoot Forms - `WithdrawlForm.cs`, `DepositForm.cs`, and `InterestForm.cs`. I have two classes, Account.cs  and its derived class `SavingsAccount.cs`. I am trying to change the `InterestRate` in the string below to the interest rate inputted by the user on the `InterestForm`. This code is located on the `SavingsAccount` class .cs file.

```
     public new string toString()
    {
        return String.Format("Account Number: {0} Balance: {1:C} Interest Rate: {2:P}", AccountNumber, AccountBalance, InterestRate);
    }
```

The full SavingsAccount.cs file

```
namespace Assignment_6_third_attempt
{
public class SavingsAccount : Account
{
    private InterestForm interestForm = new InterestForm();

    private double interestRate = 0.0;

    #region Constructors
    public SavingsAccount(int accountNumber)
    {
        base.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    public SavingsAccount() { }
    #endregion

   double InterestRate 
   {
        get { return interestForm.interestRate ; }
        set { interestRate = interestForm.interestRate; }
    }

    public double Interest(double amount)
    {
        InterestRate = interestForm.interestRate;
        return InterestRate;          
    }


    public void AddInterest(double amount)
    {
        //interestForm.CalculateInterest();
        AccountBalance = amount;
    }


    public new string toString()
    {
        return String.Format("Account Number: {0} Balance: {1:C} Interest Rate: {2:P}", AccountNumber, AccountBalance, InterestRate);
    }       
}
}
```

And here is my AccountForm.cs file (this form is the Master Form, where account number, account balance, and interest rate are displayed.

```
 namespace Assignment_6_third_attempt
{
public partial class AccountForm : Form
{
    SavingsAccount savingsAccount;
    public System.Windows.Forms.Label labelInformation;

    public AccountForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        labelInformation = accountInfoLabel;
    }

    private void createAccountButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int newAccountNumber = random.Next(0, 1000000);
        savingsAccount = new SavingsAccount(newAccountNumber);

        MessageBox.Show(savingsAccount.toString());
        accountInfoLabel.Text = savingsAccount.toString();
        depositButton.Enabled = true;
        withdrawalButton.Enabled = true;
        interestButton.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void depositButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DepositForm depForm = new DepositForm();
        depForm.ShowDialog();
        savingsAccount.Deposit((double)depForm.DepositAmount);
        accountInfoLabel.Text = savingsAccount.toString();
    }

    private void withdrawalButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            WithdrawalForm withdrawForm = new WithdrawalForm();
            withdrawForm.ShowDialog();
            savingsAccount.Withdraw((double)withdrawForm.WithdrawAmount);
            accountInfoLabel.Text = savingsAccount.toString();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void closeAccountButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        depositButton.Enabled = false;
        withdrawalButton.Enabled = false;
        accountInfoLabel.Text = "";

        savingsAccount = null; //this will clean it up off the heap.
    }



    private void interestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InterestForm interestForm = new InterestForm(savingsAccount.AccountBalance);
        interestForm.ShowDialog();
        savingsAccount.AddInterest(interestForm.CalculateInterest());           
        accountInfoLabel.Text = savingsAccount.toString();
        savingsAccount.Interest(interestForm.interestRate);
        accountInfoLabel.Text = savingsAccount.toString();
        }


    }
}
```

Lastly, here is my InterestForm.cs code, where the user can input a term and rate in an NumericUpDown control.

```
 namespace Assignment_6_third_attempt
{
 public partial class InterestForm : Form
{

    private Account account = new Account();
    //private double accountBalance;
    public double interestRate = 0.0;

    public InterestForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public InterestForm(double accountBalance) : this()
    {

        //InitializeComponent();
        account.AccountBalance = accountBalance;
    }


    private void addInterestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double interestRate = double.Parse(interestUpDown.Text);
        CalculateInterest();
        this.Close();
    }



    public double CalculateInterest()
    {
        //A = P(1 + rt)
        double accountBalance = account.AccountBalance;            
        double interestRate = (double)interestUpDown.Value;
        double term = (double)termUpDown.Value;
        double estimateInterest = (accountBalance * (1 + (interestRate * term)));
        return estimateInterest;
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Visual Basic eh? I see none. This is C#. What's the VBA connection?

Comment: I think he means Visual Studio :D

Comment: Yes I meant Visual Studio, is this very different from VBA? Sorry for the misleading tag! I am also a 'she.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:**

Apart from *all* original issues mentioned, you seem to confuse the scope of your `interestRate` `private` **field** with `interestRate` **local variable** here:

```
private void addInterestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double interestRate = double.Parse(interestUpDown.Text); //this is local variable!!
    CalculateInterest();
    this.Close();
}
```

Note that you use *local* `interestRate`, *not* your class' `interestRate`. Again, be careful with the variable's scope. Local variable cannot be accessed globally and if you have the same variable name in the local method, you have to distinguish it with the global variable (class' field) which uses `this` keyword (`this.VariableName` is field but `VariableName` is local).

In your case above, simply use the `class` field `interestRate` instead of defining new local variable `interestRate`:

```
private void addInterestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    interestRate = double.Parse(interestUpDown.Text); //remove the double
    CalculateInterest();
    this.Close();
}
```

**Original:**

The `setter` and `getter` of the `InterestRate` seems... *asymmetric*:

```
double InterestRate 
{
    get { return interestForm.interestRate ; } //you get from other form
    set { interestRate = interestForm.interestRate; } //and you set from other form
}
```

You get `interestForm.interestRate` from other form and you set it to `interestRate` in your `Form` but you never use local `interestRate`. Change that into:

```
double InterestRate 
{
    get { return interestRate ; }
    set { interestRate = value; }
}
```

That goes the same for your `Interest`:

```
public double Interest(double amount)
{
    InterestRate = interestForm.interestRate;
    return InterestRate;          
}
```

You again use your private `Form` which is unused in the class apart from being constructed. Use your `amount` instead:

```
public double Interest(double amount)
{
    InterestRate = amount; //change into this
    return InterestRate;          
}
```

Now, note also:

```
private void interestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InterestForm interestForm = new InterestForm(savingsAccount.AccountBalance);
    interestForm.ShowDialog();
    savingsAccount.AddInterest(interestForm.CalculateInterest());           
    accountInfoLabel.Text = savingsAccount.toString();
    savingsAccount.Interest(interestForm.interestRate);
    accountInfoLabel.Text = savingsAccount.toString();
}
```

You have `InterestForm` declared there, but it is a `new` `InterestForm`, it is not your `private` `InterestForm` in your `SavingAccount`. In short, the `InterestForm` you declare and the `InterestForm` in your `SavingAccount` are *two* different form instances though they share the same name `interestForm`. Look at the access modifiers - *not* the name of the instance - to know the scope of your `object`.

That being said, the design above to use non-field `InterestForm` to fill up your interest is OK. I would even say, to use private `InterestForm` is not needed. You only need to pass the value the external `InterestForm` has to your `SavingAccount` instance, not to create private `InterestForm` for your `SavingAccount`

Comment: This is how I had the code originally, I changed it back per your suggestion. However, this still returns an interestRate of 0.

Comment: @R.Schiff How do you call `toString` - I note another issue here that `toString` is different from `ToString` since C# is case sensitive, unlike VB.Net

Comment: @R.Schiff seems like there is another issue in your code, another scope confusion I would say... check out my `edit`

Comment: thank you that worked! Finally, it's been three days of stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Never declare a method with the keyword "new", use override instead.  New is something I'd only allow the most senior developers to use, and they won't use it anyway except for resolving static method signature conflicts.  It will break things I promise.  That string will be different in different parts of your program and you won't know why!

2 - Create a public field in your InterestForm.cs named InterestRate or something.  When the user specifies the interest rate, set that field equal to the interest rate.  Then the SavingsAccount code can read it by calling interestForm.InterestRate.

3 - Eventually you will gag a little when you see data classes that know about their forms or view classes.  But for now, it's fine.

Comment: 1. Thanks for the insight! I tried making the change from new to override, however this through an error. That leads down a rabbit hole of errors.                                                                                                 2. Created a public field called InterestRate in my interest Form that takes the information inputted by the user, however, this doesn't change that the SavingsAccount.InterestRate.get returns 0.                      3. Yes this is pretty messy, this is my first class with any coding ever. Sorry for all the disregard of coding etiquette. :)

Comment: We have no hate for learners - we all went through it :)  Keep on keeping on and you'll be among the best one day.